# Изменение глобальной переменной из функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var vis_week = 7, unwis_week = 0;

function newWeek() {

  $('.nav-table-action').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('nav-prev')) {
      vis_week -= 7;
      unwis_week -= 7;
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('nav-next')) {
      vis_week += 7;
      unwis_week += 7;
    }

    console.log(vis_week);
    console.log(unwis_week);
  })

}
newWeek();

$('.table-week-body>div').each(function() {
  var disabled_block = $(this).children('div:not(:lt(' + vis_week + '))').addClass('dasabled-date');
  $(this).children('div:lt(' + unwis_week + ')').addClass('dasabled-date');
})
```

Задача в том, чтобы менять глобальные значения переменных `vis_week` и `unwis_week` в последней функции. Но после клика, значение в последней функции не меняется. Понимаю, что проблема где-то в наследовании, но не могу разобраться как решить проблему

Пытаюсь реализовать календарь который будет выводить данные понедельно.

Comment: если елемент по котором ви кликаете не имеет ни единого класа с етого списка : `nav-prev` , `nav-next`, то ничего и не будет меняться

Comment: он имеет эти классы. в консоли все выводится норм. там значение меняется, но в $('.table-week-body>div').each(function() не меняется

Comment: а с чего оно там должно меняться ? етот код виполняеться сразу, а клики когда получиться...